# strange Enumerator behavior (side effects?)

Tags: ruby

There's something I don't get about the `Enumerable::take` method here. My code is supposed to generate a list of `n` sized arrays of consecutives prime numbers.

It works just fine when I use the `next` method, whereas `take(n)` returns something I can't explain. Here's the code:

**edit** *The `shift` method seems to be the issue here (see below). I still don't get why, though*

```
require 'prime'

def consecutives(size)
  Enumerator.new do |enum|
    ps = Prime.lazy       # all primes numbers
    a = Prime.take(size)  # itinialize the array
    size.times{ps.next}   # skip the first <size> values from ps
    loop do 
      enum << a           # return result
      a << ps.next        # add next prime number
      a.shift             # remove first item from a
    end
  end
end

c3 = consecutives(3) #create an iterator for arrays of size 3
```

Now using `next` works just fine:

```
3.times { p c3.next}  #=> [[2,3,5],[3,5,7],[5,7,11]]
```

Whereas `take` returns something I don't get at all :

```
p c3.take(3) #=> [[5, 7, 11], [5, 7, 11], [5, 7, 11]]
```

Any idea about what's happening here ?

**edit** replacing `a << ps.next ; a.shift` by `a = (a+ [ps.next])[-1..1]` does actually solve the issue, and the enumerator behaves as expected.
I still don't get what's happening here though, so I guess the question stays relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem:

```
  enum << a           # return result
```

Here you yield an array. Or so you think. Under the hood, a **reference** to array is passed. Then you go on and modify the array you think to be your internal. In reality, those modifications affect **both** arrays, since there's really only one array in memory and two references to it. In the end, you get the same one array and 4 references (one internal and three yielded).

The workaround you found works because there you create a **new** array. Simply calling `.dup` would also suffice.

```
require 'prime'

def consecutives(size)
  Enumerator.new do |enum|
    ps = Prime.lazy      
    a = Prime.take(size) 
    size.times{ps.next}  
    loop do 
      enum << a.dup  # <== here    
      a << ps.next       
      a.shift            
    end
  end
end

c3 = consecutives(3) 

c3.take(3) # => [[2, 3, 5], [3, 5, 7], [5, 7, 11]]
```

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right. Not the first time I get confused by thinking a reference is an actual value -_-. Thanks !

Comment: @aherve: it's my pleasure :)